# VBA combo box change event if value does not equal then msgbox

Tags: combobox, case, userform

EDIT: Example, I have order "ASO-10001" I change the status to "Closed" in my userform, but forget to change the stage to closed too. So, a 'reminder' msgbox pops up if status equals "closed" AND stage does NOT equal "closed.

Works perfectly.

However, I have order "TSO-20300" the status equals "closed" AND the stage equals "closed". If I click on TSO-20300 in my listbox (lstMaster_Click()) or if I type TSO-20300 in a textbox (txtSearch) and click on the search command button (cmbSearch_Click()), the message pops up when it shouldn't.

I've edited the code below by adding 'comments' below Case "Closed" that show three different codes I've tried.

```
Private Sub cboStatus_Change()
    With Me.cboStatus
        Select Case .Value
        Case "Standby"
            .BackColor = &HC0FFFF 'Yellow
            txtE10Status.BackColor = &HC0FFFF 'Yellow
            txtE10Status.Text = "Standby"
        Case "Open"
            .BackColor = &HC0FFC0 'Green
            txtE10Status.BackColor = &HC0FFC0 'Green
            txtE10Status.Text = "Open"
                Case "Closed"
            .BackColor = &HC0C0FF 'Red
            txtE10Status.BackColor = &HC0C0FF 'Red
            txtE10Status.Text = "Closed"
            'MsgBox "Change the Stage to: 08 Order Closed in Epicor" & vbCrLf & "and make sure the Responsible field is left blank.", vbInformation, "Set Epicor Stage to Closed"
                'If InStr(1, cboStatus.Text, "Closed", vbTextCompare) And InStr(1, cboStage.Text, "08 Order Closed in Epicor", 1) = 0 Then
                    'MsgBox "Change the Stage to: 08 Order Closed in Epicor" & vbCrLf & "and make sure the Responsible field is left blank.", vbInformation, "Set Epicor Stage to Closed"
                'If Me.cboStage.Value <> "08 Order Closed in Epicor" Then 'Message appears if cboStatus Case = "Closed" and cboStage.Value <> "08 Order Closed in Epicor"
                    'MsgBox "Change the Stage to: 08 Order Closed in Epicor" & vbCrLf & "and make sure the Responsible field is left blank.", vbInformation, "Set Epicor Stage to Closed"
                'Else
                    'do nothing-----this isn't working the message still pops up even if cboStatus Case = "Closed" and cboStage.Value = "08 Order Closed in Epicor".
                'End If
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```